# C++ Pointers Scope

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to use an array I created in another function in my main function.

```
int main()
{
    string *key;
    string *morse;
    createArray(fileName, &key, &morse, size);
}

void createArray(string fileName, string **key, string **morse, int size)
{
    *key = new string[size];
    *morse = new string[size];
    (*key)[position-1] = currentKey;
    (*morse)[position-1] = currentMorse;
}
```

Now how can I use the contents of those two string arrays in my main function? For example, I need to use `str.find();` in the main() function.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Using `.` operator

```
key[position].find( "xyz" ) ;
```

Also, since you're manually managing memory, you need to free resources once used, to avoid memory leak

```
delete [] key;
delete [] morse ;
```

Comment: Not sure if that's what OP really wants. key is an array, maybe key[index].find("xyz")?

Comment: @TonyJiang Opps sorry, fixed

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. But I think my question was unclear. I'm trying to search through key and morse in my main function, but morse and key weren't created until after I used 'createArray()'.

Comment: @Steven So use above after creating those arrays, what's the issue ? I don't if `key` should be present in `morse` or vice versa, just use a for loop to loop over `position` and so on